# Show newly printed text in textarea in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where a web application is printing information to a `textarea` that is acting like a console.

For simplicities sake, it is declared like this:

```
<textarea id = "console" readonly></textarea>
```

I have a function that prints new text to this window when the web application calls it:

```
function printToConsole(text) {
    $('#console').val($('#console').val() + text);
    // INSERT NEW CODE HERE
}
```

Currently this function prints to the console just fine, but I have to scroll down every time to see the new information coming back. There has to be some way of using focus, etc to have it automatically scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop()` method like following.

```js
function printToConsole(text) {
    var newVal = $('#console').val() + text;
    $('#console').focus().val('').val(newVal); //to focus at the end of text
    $('#console').scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);
}

var i=0;
$('button').click(function(){
    printToConsole('Add text '+(++i)+'\n');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id = "console" style="height: 70px;" readonly></textarea>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Hey Azim, thanks for the answer, worked like a charm. One thing about the code is I don't understand why you need the '[0]' reference in this particular instance before calling "scrollHeight". I would have expected it to be a call like $('#console').scrolHeight.

Comment: `scrollHeight` is a javascript property & `$('#console')[0]` will give the javascript element as like `document.getElementById("console")` . @samuelnj

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printToConsole(text) {
  let $console = $("#console");
  $console.val($console.val() + text);
  $console.prop("scrollTop", $console.prop("scrollHeight"));
}


printToConsole(`
print to console
print to console
print to console
print to console
this is the line that shows`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id = "console" readonly></textarea>
```